# What is Dua Qunut and when should we recite it in the Prayer/Salat?

Tags: salat, dua

Assalamualaikum everyone. As the title says: What is Dua Qunut and when should we recite it in the Prayer/Salat?
Please post the Dua/Sura too. I need to learn it

Comment: It is a Dua - you can read about it [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/9061) and [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/14093) and [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/20031).

Comment: As to when to recite it can be found in my answer https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14941/is-reciting-qunoot-mandatory-in-fajr-salat

Answer (score 3):

This [page](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=3394) from islamweb contains two versions of Dua' Al Kunout, you can read also that it is a Sunna not Fard, and your prayer won't be wrong if you forget it, or left it.

Dua' Al Kunout is:

> "اللهم اهدني فيمن هديت وعافني فيمن عافيت وتولني فيمن توليت وبارك لي
>   فيما أعطيت  وقني شر ما قضيت إنك تقضي ولا يقضى عليك وإنه لا يذل من
>   واليت ولا يعز من عاديت  تباركت ربنا وتعاليت"

It can be recited in Fajr Prayer after the Ruku' of the second Rek'a, but it is more preferred to be recited during Witr Prayer (After salat al Eisha'), also after the Ruku' of the last Reka'.

Answer (score 1):

Qunut can be any dua you like to recite to Allah, you recite it after the second surah in the second rek'a.

It is mustahab(sunnah) and not fard.