# Is reciting qunoot mandatory in fajr salat?

Tags: dua, wajib

In shaafi's book, I have studied that 'Qunoot is mandatory in fajr salat', after returning from second ruku, we have to recite Qunoot at childhood. After that, I'm not having believe on shaafi, hanafi.

So, I want to know that, whether reciting Qunoot is mandatory for fajr/any salat according to the Quran and Sunnah?

Comment: No It isn't reciting but the better you do it

Comment: In accordance with Shia, tis not mandatory to recite the qonut, but tis better...

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can find out, it's not mandatory (wajib).

> It is better for the imam to limit Qunoot to times of calamity,
>   following the example of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings
>   of Allaah be upon him), as it was proven that Abu Maalik al-Ash’ari
>   said: “I said to my father, ‘O my father, you prayed behind the
>   Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and
>   behind Abu Bakr, ‘Umar, ‘Uthmaan and ‘Ali (may Allaah be pleased with
>   them). Did they used to say Du’aa’ al-Qunoot in Fajr?’ He said, ‘O my
>   son, this is a newly-invented matter.’” (Narrated by the five, apart
>   from Abu Dawood; classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in al-Irwa’, 435).

Sources:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js0YYo5nPfg

http://islamqa.info/en/20031

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't mandatory. It is a good sunna in most madhabs and abrogated according to some others because of the hadith:

> Abu Salama b. Abd al-Rahman b. 'Auf heard Abu Huraira say:
>
> (When) Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) (wished to invoke curse or blessing on
>   someone, he would do so at the end) of the recitation in the dawn
>   prayer, when he had pronounced Allah-o-Akbar (for bending) and then
>   lifted his head (saying):" Allah listened to him who praised Him; our
>   Lord! to Thee is all praise" ; he would then stand up and say:" Rescue
>   al-Walid b. Walid, Salama b. Hisham, and 'Ayyash b. Abd Rabi'a, and
>   the helpless among the Muslims. O Allah! trample severely Mudar and
>   cause them a famine (which broke out at the time) of Joseph. O Allah!
>   curse Lihyan, Ri'l, Dhakwan, 'Usayya, for they disobeyed Allah and His
>   Messenger."
>
> (The narrator then adds): The news reached us that he abandoned
>   (this) when this verse was revealed:" Thou but no concern in the
>   matter whether He turns to them (mercifully) or chastises them; surely
>   they are wrongdoers" (Surat al-'Imran (3:128)]
>
> [Sahih Muslim and partly in other Hadith books like Sahih al-Bukhari]

And well it was narrated to be done before or after the ruku'.

> It was narrated that Anas bin Malik said: He was asked about Qunut in
>   the Subh prayer, and he said: “We used to recite Qunut before Ruku’
>   and afterwards.”
>
> [Sunan ibn Majah]
>
> Al-Bara bin Azib narrated: "The Prophet (S) would perform the Qunut in
>   the Subh and Maghrib prayers."
>
> [Jami' at-Tirmidhi]

Some madhabs regard it to be a sunna in 2nd raka'a of the fajr/sobh fard prayer others in the witr prayer. At least one can do it in any Prayer if the situation require it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the viewpoint of Shia Maraja’s (marajeul-Taghlid),

> it is considered as a Mustahab(recommended) deed at all prayers.
>
> توضیح المسائل مراجع، ج 1، ص 603   مسئله 1117 (Tuzihol-Masaael Maraje’
>   Vol.1, page603, M.1117) )

with respect to your question that you inquired regarding the mentioned matter in Quran, I ought to tell you that unfortunately I could not find the mentioned issue in the holy Quran. But as I pointed out before, it is considered as a recommended (Mustahab) issue.

**Source**:

[http://islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa4984)

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not mandatory. But reading qunut is a good Sunnah especially in facing disaster or calamity.

Comment: Salaam and welcome to Islam.SE. Here we prefer answers to be substantial and provide supportive evidences. Please go through the help center especially [the guidelines on answering](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).